# A word that means that something is not real but feels real

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to describe this room that takes me to places, a bit like a teleporter. However, its just my imagination playing around with me. Is there any word to describe something that is **not** real but **feels** real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/virtual) : (from TFD)

> - Existing or resulting in essence or effect though not in actual fact, form, or name.
> - Existing in the mind, especially as a product of the imagination.

Virtual Reality (VR): ( from Wikipedia)

> - sometimes referred to as immersive multimedia, is a computer-simulated environment that can simulate physical presence in places in the real world or imagined worlds. Virtual reality can recreate sensory experiences, which include virtual taste, sight, smell, sound, touch, etc.

Comment: According to two dictionaries I've looked in, *virtual reality* is computer generated. I do not think that is what the OP had in mind when they asked the question.

Comment: @WS2 -    The term that fits OP question is 'virtual'. Virtual reality is an additional piece I added just to show a common usage of 'virtual'.

Comment: But I don't see how the OP could use it in her context without calling it *virtual reality*. And it would give a false impression that it was computer generated. Indeed all meanings of *virtual* other than the original and literal one, are connected to some scientific discipline - optics, mechanics, physics. None of them deal with human imagining. (ODO)

Comment: Virtual does not refer only to something that is computer generated. Computer science  use this term as it well  fits the context of something apparently real.!!

Answer (score 4):

il·lu·so·ry

based on illusion; not real.
"she knew the safety of her room was illusory"

Comment: I've never met a *virtual* reality that felt real, but illusions, or even delusions, can seem real as rocks, until they're shattered.

Answer (score 1):

I think some people might call it ***suspended reality***.

Answer (score 1):

A simulacrum may be a useful choice - a copy of the real?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, even if it's correct, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is [verisimilitude.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=verisimilitude&searchmode=none)

> "Appearance of truth or reality, likelihood,..."

Answer (score 0):

surreal (mix of fact & fantasy)

Answer (score 0):

Fata morgana
Phantom
Are you thinking of something like the Transformation Room in "Harry Potter" series?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fata_Morgana_(mirage)

Comment: Could you please provide a brief summary of what a *Fata Morgana (mirage) is. You can just copy&paste the intro if you prefer, I think it's an interesting suggestion and I have no idea what Harry Potter has got to do with this. But you see, I've never watched nor read any of the stories.

Answer (score 0):

**Hallucination** might be an option:

> a sensory experience of something that does not exist outside the mind, caused by various physical and mental disorders, or by reaction to certain toxic substances, and usually manifested as visual or auditory images.

[Definition at dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hallucination?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

Realistic. Representing things in a way that is accurate and true to life.
"a realistic human drama"

Synonyms:   true to life, lifelike, true, truthful, faithful, real-life, close, naturalistic, authentic, genuine, representational, graphic, convincing; vérité; informal: kitchen-sink, warts and all; rare: verisimilar, veristic, speaking.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! From the format of your answer, it appears that you copy-pasted it from somewhere. If that is the case, you **must** acknowledge your source.